# How filter PySpark DataFrame with PySpark for current date

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I have a dataframe with the following fields

[image]

I'm trying to use PySpark to filter on SaleDate where the SaleDate is the current date.

My attempt is as follows

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import col

df.where((col("SaleDate") = to_date())
```

This is assuming todays date is 16/10/2021

I keep on getting the error:

```
SyntaxError: keyword can't be an expression (<stdin>, line 2)
```

I should mention that the SaleDate is actually a StringType() and not DateType as shown in the image.

|-- SaleDate: string (nullable = true)

Comment: In your attempt,  in your `where` clause, you're using assignment equal operator `=` instead of comparison equal operator `==`.  Moreover, there is an extra `(` in your expression. Can you correct your attempt so it can be executed by replacing `df.where((col("SaleDate") = to_date())` by `df.where(col("SaleDate") == to_date())` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use [`current_date` function](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.current_date.html) to get the current date instead of `to_date`.

So you first need to convert value in `SaleDate` column from string to date with `to_date`, then compare the obtained date with `current_date`:

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

df.where(F.to_date('SaleDate', 'yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss.SSS') == F.current_date())
```